# Transparent Form Woes (Form shows up black, form doesn't show up at all)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, mouse

I'm trying to create a transparent form that will still respond to mouse move and click events, to show our company's logo until the user clicks the mouse, but I'm having a bit of difficulty in that sometimes the form and logo won't show up at all, and in other times they'll show up, but with a black background.

Here's how I call my form:

```
MouseAlertForm maf = new MouseAlertForm(Win32.GetCursorPosition());
maf.Show();
```

`maf.Show()` causes the form to not show up at all (Same for `Show(this)`), and `maf.ShowDialog()` causes the black background. Here's the code for `MouseAlertForm`.

```
public sealed partial class MouseAlertForm : Form
{
    private Image Logo;
    public Point MouseLocation { get; private set; }

    public MouseAlertForm(Point location)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseLocation = location; 

        // Allow transparent backgrounds.
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        // Set up this form to be maximum size, with no borders, and have a nearly transparent background.
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1,255,255,255);

        // Load the Image.
        var assemlby = Assembly.GetAssembly(new AssemblyTypeLinker().GetType());
        if (assemlby != null)
            Logo = Image.FromStream(assemlby.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram.MyLogo.png"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the current mouse location, and invalidate the control causing a re-draw.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        MouseLocation = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release our logo, and close the form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        Logo.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear what was previously drawn, and if we have a mouse location, draw the logo in that area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // Clear the background back to a nearly transparent white.
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 255, 255));

        if (MouseLocation != Point.Empty)
        {
            // Draw our logo in the spot of the current mouse location.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Logo, MouseLocation.X - 100, MouseLocation.Y - 100, 200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It seems like there is a black background being created even under what I would consider to be the background. I set my `BackColor` to the full 255, and made it Blue, and then slowly reduced the alpha component down to 0, which just leaves the black background I was seeing. Is this a characteristic of ShowDialog? Where is this background coming from?

Comment: Must it be a form, why not a panel?

Comment: A Panel could work too, let me give that a shot! I don't really mind what it is, as long as it takes up the entire desktop, is transparent, and can show my logo. :)

Comment: @gaynorvader I'm still not having any luck. Keep in mind this is being launched from an application that itself doesn't not have any form, only a Taskbar Icon.

Comment: I recall attempting to make forms fade in and out by fiddling with the opacity. Whenever you switch from 100% to anything else it results in the form flickering black and occasionally staying black. I resolved it by only ever going up to 99.9% opacity. I'm not sure if that's relevant to your issue of colour switching but it might be worth thinking about.

Comment: The problem with setting the opacity is that then the call to e.Graphics.DrawImage also respects the same opacity, when the image it's drawing should be fully visible. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: The calls to Paint the Form do not automatically cause what's behind the Form to Paint, hence the black box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix. First, since I'm now overriding `OnPaint`, whereas in a previous implementation I was no, I was using `CreateGraphics()` a lot. But since I'm overriding `OnPaint`, it comes with it's own graphics object, which is cleared for me when it is Invalidated, therefore I do not need to clear it myself.

Second, and I don't know why, but previously using a `BackColor` with a `TransparencyKey` caused the `MouseMove` and `MouseClick` events to not be registered, but again, I believe since I'm overriding them opposed to attaching to them, they are being fired despite the `TransparencyKey`.

```
public sealed partial class MouseAlertForm : Form
{
    private Image Logo;
    public Point MouseLocation { get; private set; }

    public MouseAlertForm(Point location)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseLocation = location; 

        // Allow transparent backgrounds.
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        // Set up this form to be maximum size, with no borders, and have a nearly transparent background.
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        this.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;

        // Load the Image.
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(new AssemblyTypeLinker().GetType());
        if (assembly != null)
            Logo = Image.FromStream(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram.MyLogo.png"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the current mouse location, and invalidate the control causing a re-draw.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        MouseLocation = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release our logo, and close the form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        Logo.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear what was previously drawn, and if we have a mouse location, draw the logo in that area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (MouseLocation != Point.Empty)
        {
            // Draw our logo in the spot of the current mouse location.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Logo, MouseLocation.X - 100, MouseLocation.Y - 100, 200, 200);
        }
    }
```